# Rails routes matching query parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Rails routes are great for matching RESTful style **'/'** separated bits of a URL, but can I match query parameters in a `map.connect` config. I want different **controllers/actions** to be invoked depending on the presence of a parameter after the `'?'`.

I was trying something like this...

```
map.connect "api/my/path?apple=:applecode", :controller => 'apples_controller', :action => 'my_action'
map.connect "api/my/path?banana=:bananacode", :controller => 'bananas_controller', :action => 'my_action'
```

For routing purposes I don't care about the value of the parameter, as long as it is available to the controller in the `params` hash

Comment: This is probably going to be really tricky to do with the built-in routing engine because it only deals with the path portion of the request. Query parameters are parsed by another layer. It might be possible to use Rack to re-write the URL as it comes in to make it routable.

Answer (score 11):

The following solution is based on the "Advanced Constraints" section of the "Rails Routing from the Outside In" rails guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

In your config/routes.rb file, include a recognizer class have a matches? method, e.g.:

```
class FruitRecognizer
  def initialize(fruit_type)
    @fruit_type = fruit_type.to_sym
  end

  def matches?(request)
    request.params.has_key?(@fruit_type)
  end
end
```

Then use objects from the class as routing constraints, as in:

```
map.connect "api/my/path", :contraints => FruitRecognizer.new(:apple), :controller => 'apples_controller', :action => 'my_action'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a concrete reason why you can't change this, why not just make it restful?

`map.connect "api/my/path/bananas/:id, :controller => "bananas_controller", :action => "my_action"`

If you have many parameters, why not use a `POST` or a `PUT` so that your parameters don't need to be exposed by the url?