# How to map non-REST URLS to REST ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have a small rails app that has default scaffold generated routes eg. `/stadia/1.xml`. However I have to support legacy client app that can't construct such URLs correctly. What I need to do is to map URL in the form:

`/stadia?id=1?format=xml` to `/stadia/1.xml`

Or even something like:

`/myApp?model=<model_name>?id=<id>?format=xml` to `/<model_name/<id>.xml`

Is it possible to craft appropriate route in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have good answer for this. What I would do is change first part of url to `/stadia_legacy` for legacy urls or change first part of urls for RESTful routes.

Then you can map in routes:

```
map.stadia_legacy :stadia_legacy, :controller => 'stadias', :action => 'please_redirect_me'
```

Then in stadias controller in action `please_redirect_me` you can check all params (they are availble in `params` hash: `params[:id]`, `params[:format]` etc.) and redirect to correct url. Or you can write all routes manualy to correct controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do some url rewrite in apache ?

Comment: A blanket statement like this does not help the OP much. I would be helpful to provide at least an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: Sometimes, people works with old existing code, and can't deal with "oh why didn't we rewrote the whole app, and the whole urls in our app ?" It's a workaround, so, but it's quick, and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

[I had a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811080/rails-routes-matching-query-parameters). No answers so far, so it seems routes.rb config doesn't offer an easy way of doing this (routing based on query parameters), which I find surprising actually.

So an ugly workaround would be to have a 'myApp' default route, and then have a special redirecting controller which would look at the query params (because in controllers you *do* have access to that) and redirect accordingly.