# Rails different route if parameter is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Small routing question:

I want

- `myapp.com/my_controller` -> lead to **controller A**
- `myapp.com/my_controller?uid=123` -> lead to **controller B**

any ideas how to change the routs file (in rails 2.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rails 2.3.1:**

```
map.route_a 'my_controller', :controller => "A", :action => "a"
map.route_b 'my_controller/uid/:uid', :controller => "B", :action => "b"
```

You should get `route_a_url` and `route_b_url(:uid => uid)` helper method to generate urls. Its not exactly query parameters but its using `uid` and a value both.

**Rails 3.2.1:**

```
match 'my_controller' => 'A#a', :as => 'route_a'
match 'my_controller/uid/:uid' => 'B#b', :as => 'route_b'
```

And the helper functions `route_a_url` and `route_b_url(:uid=>10)` were readily available.

**Explnation:**

---

In your view, use the helper functions to generate urls

**Helper Function:** `route_a_url()`
**Generated URL:** `http://localhost:3000/my_controller`
**Map to:** `Controller A, Action a`

**Helper Function:** `route_b_url(:uid => 10))`
**Generated URL:** `http://localhost:3000/my_controller/uid/10`
**Map to:** `Controller B, Action b`

Comment: Did you try with `:my_controller/uid/:uid` instead of `:my_controller?uid=:uid`?

Comment: hmm... i will try it in rails 2.3 myself. Meanwhile you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7624036/1160106

Comment: hmm lastly, i tried with your version and it worked for me too... Here is the code snippet from my rails 2.3.2 app. **https://gist.github.com/3822574**. Note that there was a mistake about **`:`** in the which i fixed now. Would you check it now?

Comment: see im using '?uid=XXX' to pass the uid param

Comment: oh your url is `http://localhost:3000/widget?uid=123` but to match with the route it should be `http://localhost:3000/widget/uid/123`. By default the query params are not a part of RESTful urls. So it will match only the main url part. Hence it matches with `home` controller. Try use the helper function to generate the urls. Ive updated my answer with a bit more explanation.